# Access VB not importing all Excel colmns

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel-import

I'm importing an Excel Spreadsheet via VB in Access 2013. 
The code brings in all the data from all the tabs except 1.  On that tab it only brings in the first column out of the 50 columns.  I have the range hard coded (see below)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "Provider-Locations", ImportFile, True, "Provider-Locations!A1:A0500"

What I've tried
All the data comes in if I do the import manually. (That isn't a viable approach because I'm automating a monthly manual process.)

I thought it was an issue with spreadsheet because the same issue is happening the spreadsheets I'm importing. So, I copied the data and pasted just the values into a new spreadsheet and the issue still happens.

Help! I'm banging my head against the wall.

Comment: Are there any protection on the cells of the spreadsheet that could be preventing the data from being copied? Even when you copied the data from one spreadsheet to another, the likelihood of copying the properties as well is possible.

Comment: Thanks  That helped me find the issue.  The issue was how the data table was set up in the spreadsheet